# Setting up JSF projects for Eclipse palette

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I have a JSF project in ECipse JUNO. OEPE is installed in eclipse. In palette I select a JSF HTML tag like "Select One Radio". In the opened dialog box, I click on buttons located to the right of attribute "value". "choose binding" dialog box appears which is empty with error "Unable to access bind data, check project configuration". Could you please let me know why I don't see any managed bean there? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I switched to Eclipse Kepler and now it works fine.